$n$-th derivative of $\exp\left(-\frac{\lambda(x-\mu)^2}{2\mu^2x}\right)$
Let $\lambda$ and $\mu$ be two positive real numbers and let denote $f$ the function defined as:
$$\forall x>0,~f(x):= \exp\left(-\frac{\lambda(x-\mu)^2}{2\mu^2x}\right)$$
According to WolframAlpha (WA), the $n$-th derivative is (see below):
$$\tag{1}\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, ~\partial_x^n = x^{-n}f(x)\sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^j\frac{(1+j-k-n)_n}{k! (k-j)!}\left(\frac{-\lambda(x-\mu)^2}{2\mu^2 x}\right)^k.$$
The 1-st derivative case
The first derivative (and I checked it numerically) is given by:
$$f'(x) = -\lambda\frac{(x+\mu)(x-\mu)}{2\mu^2 x^2}f(x).$$
However, applying (1) to $n=1$ leads to:
$$f'(x) = \left(\frac{\lambda(x-\mu)^2}{2\mu^2 x^2}\right)f(x)$$
which are clearly not the same functions.
Can someone help me to find the mistake (mine or WA) ?
Thank you very much!

[Edit]
Screenshot from WA website:

query:
 n-th derivative of exp(-\lambda*(x-\mu)**2/(2*\mu**2*x))

Do you think the exponent in your expression is 2/(2*\mu*x) or just 2 ? You may need parentheses around the entire exponent. Your expression as written may really be $\exp\left(-\tfrac{\lambda(x-\mu)^2}{2\mu x}\right)$.

Hi @MPW, thank you for your interest. However, considering WA screenshot, this is expression I would like to differentiate. (I might misunderstand what you mean...)

You are missing a factor of $\mu$ in the denominator of the argument of $\exp$ in your wolfram alpha query.

Thank you! I will edit the post since the WA answer is still not convincing.

Summation has 3 terms : $k=0,j=0$ : $k=1,j=0$ : $k=1,j=1$

Yes @Prem, but the first and the last one vanish because of the rising factorial term

$k!$ in the denominator of your formula (1) doesn't match $j!$ in the denominator of the WolframAlpha screenshot, but this doesn't resolve the problem.

It is easy to see that we can write
\begin{equation*}
h(x)=\ln f(x)=-\frac{\lambda(x-\mu)^2}{2\mu^2x}=\frac{\lambda}{2\mu^2}\biggl(2\mu-x-\frac{\mu^2}{x}\biggr).
\end{equation*}
Hence, its derivatives are
\begin{equation*}
h'(x)=-\frac{\lambda}{2\mu^2}\biggl(1-\frac{\mu^2}{x^2}\biggr)
=\frac{\lambda}{2}\biggl(\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{\mu^2}\biggr)
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
h^{(k+1)}(x)=(-1)^{k}\frac{\lambda}{2}\frac{(k+1)!}{x^{k+2}},\quad k\in\mathbb{N}.
\end{equation*}
Making use of the identities
$$
B_{n,k}\bigl(abx_1,ab^2x_2,\dotsc,ab^{n-k+1}x_{n-k+1}\bigr) =a^kb^n B_{n,k}(x_1,x_2,\dotsc,x_{n-k+1})
$$
and
$$
B_{n,k}(x_1,x_2,\dotsc,x_{n-k+1})
=\sum_{\ell=0}^{k}\binom{n}{\ell}x_1^\ell B_{n-\ell,k-\ell}(0,x_2,x_3,\dotsc,x_{n-k+1})
$$
for $n\ge k\ge0$, where $B_{n,k}$ stands for the partial Bell polynomials (also known as the Bell polynomials of the second kind), we arrive at
\begin{gather*}
B_{n,k}\bigl(h'(x), h''(x), \dotsc, h^{(n-k+1)}(x)\bigr)
=B_{n,k}\biggl(\frac{\lambda}{2}\biggl(\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{\mu^2}\biggr), -\frac{\lambda}{2}\frac{2!}{x^{3}}, \dotsc, (-1)^{n-k}\frac{\lambda}{2}\frac{(n-k+1)!}{x^{n-k+2}}\biggr)\\
\begin{aligned}
&=(-1)^{n+k}\biggl(\frac{\lambda}{2}\biggr)^k B_{n,k}\biggl(\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{\mu^2}, \frac{2!}{x^{3}}, \dotsc, \frac{(n-k+1)!}{x^{n-k+2}}\biggr)\\
&=(-1)^{n+k}\biggl(\frac{\lambda}{2}\biggr)^k \sum_{\ell=0}^{k}\binom{n}{\ell}\biggl(\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{\mu^2}\biggr)^\ell B_{n-\ell,k-\ell}\biggl(0, \frac{2!}{x^{3}}, \dotsc, \frac{(n-k+1)!}{x^{n-k+2}}\biggr)\\
&=(-1)^{n+k}\biggl(\frac{\lambda}{2}\biggr)^k \sum_{\ell=0}^{k}\binom{n}{\ell}\biggl(\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{\mu^2}\biggr)^\ell \frac{B_{n-\ell,k-\ell}(0,2!, \dotsc, (n-k+1)!)}{x^{n+k-2\ell}} \\
&=(-1)^{n+k}\biggl(\frac{\lambda}{2}\biggr)^k \frac{1}{x^{n+k}}\sum_{\ell=0}^{k}\binom{n}{\ell}\biggl(1-\frac{x^2}{\mu^2}\biggr)^\ell B_{n-\ell,k-\ell}(0,2!, \dotsc, (n-k+1)!)
\end{aligned}
\end{gather*}
for $n\ge k\ge0$. By the Faa di Bruno formula
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\operatorname{d}^n[f\circ h(x)]}{\operatorname{d} x^n}=\sum_{k=0}^nf^{(k)}(h(x)) B_{n,k}\bigl(h'(x),h''(x),\dotsc,h^{(n-k+1)}(x)\bigr), \quad n\ge0,
\end{equation*}
we obtain
\begin{align*}
f^{(n)}(x)&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\operatorname{e}^{h(x)} B_{n,k}\bigl(h'(x), h''(x), \dotsc, h^{(n-k+1)}(x)\bigr)\\
&=f(x)\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{n+k}\biggl(\frac{\lambda}{2}\biggr)^k \frac{1}{x^{n+k}}\sum_{\ell=0}^{k}\binom{n}{\ell}\biggl(1-\frac{x^2}{\mu^2}\biggr)^\ell B_{n-\ell,k-\ell}(0,2!, \dotsc, (n-k+1)!)\\
&=\frac{f(x)}{2^n \mu^{2n} x^{2n}}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\lambda^k (-2x)^{n-k} \sum_{\ell=0}^{k}\binom{n}{\ell} \mu^{2(n-\ell)} \bigl(\mu^2-x^2\bigr)^\ell B_{n-\ell,k-\ell}(0,2!, \dotsc, (n-k+1)!)\\
&=\frac{f(x)}{2^n \mu^{2n} x^{2n}}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\lambda^k (-2x)^{n-k} \sum_{\ell=0}^{k}\binom{n}{\ell} \binom{n-k-1}{k-\ell-1} \frac{(n-\ell)!}{(k-\ell)!} \mu^{2(n-\ell)} \bigl(\mu^2-x^2\bigr)^\ell
\end{align*}
for $n\ge0$, where the derivation
\begin{align*}
B_{n-\ell,k-\ell}(0,2!, \dotsc, (n-k+1)!)
&=\frac{(n-\ell)!}{(n-k)!} B_{n-k,k-\ell}\biggl(\frac{2!}{2},\frac{3!}{3},\dotsc, \frac{(n+\ell-2k+2)!}{n+\ell-2k+2}\biggr)\\
&=\frac{(n-\ell)!}{(n-k)!} B_{n-k,k-\ell}(1!,2!,\dotsc, (n+\ell-2k+1)!)\\
&=\frac{(n-\ell)!}{(n-k)!} \binom{n-k-1}{k-\ell-1}\frac{(n-k)!}{(k-\ell)!}\\
&=\binom{n-k-1}{k-\ell-1}\frac{(n-\ell)!}{(k-\ell)!}
\end{align*}
for $k\ge\ell\ge0$ used the identity
$$
B_{n,k}\biggl(\frac{x_2}{2},\frac{x_3}{3},\dotsc,\frac{x_{n-k+2}}{n-k+2}\biggr)
=\frac{n!}{(n+k)!}B_{n+k,k}(0,x_2,x_3,\dotsc,x_{n-k+1})
$$
and the formula
$$
B_{n,k}(1!,2!,\dotsc,(n-k+1)!)=\binom{n-1}{k-1}\frac{n!}{k!}
$$
for $n\ge k\ge0$ in sequence. In conclusion, we derive the explicit derivative formula
$$
\boxed{f^{(n)}(x)=\frac{f(x)}{2^n \mu^{2n} x^{2n}}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\lambda^k (-2x)^{n-k} \sum_{\ell=0}^{k}\binom{n}{\ell} \binom{n-k-1}{k-\ell-1} \frac{(n-\ell)!}{(k-\ell)!} \mu^{2(n-\ell)} \bigl(\mu^2-x^2\bigr)^\ell}
$$
for $n\ge0$.
References

C. A. Charalambides, Enumerative Combinatorics, CRC Press Series on Discrete Mathematics and its Applications. Chapman & Hall/CRC, Boca Raton, FL, 2002.
L. Comtet, Advanced Combinatorics: The Art of Finite and Infinite Expansions, Revised and Enlarged Edition, D. Reidel Publishing Co., 1974; available online at https://doi.org/10.1007/978-94-010-2196-8.
https://qifeng618.wordpress.com/2018/03/19/some-papers-on-explicit-formulas-of-special-values-for-the-bell-polynomials-of-the-second-kind/.


Thank you @qifebg618, that exactly what I was looking for !

What was the resolution to OP Query ? Was @NancyBoy right ? Was Wolf right ? What was the Issue ?

I am not sure whether your Question was answered , @NancyBoy , I am not even sure what this answer is claiming ! What was the eventual resolution to the Query ?

@Prem: I modified the title of this post to be more clear, sorry for this confusion. The question is about finding the $n$-th derivative of the function detailed in the post.

Hmmmm , you were getting some $1^{st}$ Derivative which did not match $n^{th}$ Derivative with $n=1$ , @NancyBoy , was it resolved why that was not matching ?

@Prem The answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4904046 is correct. But I don’t know where some error is in this answer. I checked up each step many times but didn’t find the error. I will check it up again and correct it soon.

Mathematica gives a difference root representation which leads to the formula
$$\frac{\partial^n e^{-\frac{\lambda\, (x-\mu)^2}{2\, \mu^2 x}}}{\partial x^n}=n!\, y(x,n)\tag{1}$$
where $y(x,n)$ is defined recursively as
$$y(x,n)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 e^{-\frac{\lambda  (x-\mu )^2}{2 \mu ^2 x}} & n=0 \\
 \frac{\lambda  \left(\mu ^2-x^2\right) e^{-\frac{\lambda  (x-\mu )^2}{2 \mu ^2 x}}}{2 \mu ^2 x^2} & n=1 \\
 \frac{\lambda  e^{-\frac{\lambda  (x-\mu )^2}{2 \mu ^2 x}} \left(\lambda  \mu ^4+\lambda  x^4-2 \lambda  \mu ^2 x^2-4 \mu ^4 x\right)}{8 \mu ^4 x^4} & n=2 \\
 -\frac{y(x,n-1) \left(-\lambda  \mu ^2+4 \mu ^2 (n-3) x+\lambda  x^2+8 \mu ^2 x\right)+2 y(x,n-2) \left(\mu ^2+\mu ^2 (n-3)+\lambda  x\right)+\lambda  y(x,n-3)}{2 \mu ^2 n x^2} & n\ge 3 \\
\end{array}\right.\tag{2}$$
which results in the following table of evaluations.
$$\begin{array}{cc}
 n & \frac{\partial ^ne^{-\frac{\lambda  (x-\mu )^2}{2 \mu ^2 x}}}{\partial x^n} \\
 0 & e^{-\frac{\lambda  (x-\mu )^2}{2 \mu ^2 x}} \\
 1 & \frac{\lambda  \left(\mu ^2-x^2\right) e^{-\frac{\lambda  (x-\mu )^2}{2 \mu ^2 x}}}{2 \mu ^2 x^2} \\
 2 & \frac{\lambda  e^{-\frac{\lambda  (x-\mu )^2}{2 \mu ^2 x}} \left(\lambda  \mu ^4+\lambda  x^4-2 \lambda  \mu ^2 x^2-4 \mu ^4 x\right)}{4 \mu ^4 x^4} \\
 3 & \frac{\lambda  e^{-\frac{\lambda  (x-\mu )^2}{2 \mu ^2 x}} \left(-\lambda ^2 x^6+3 \lambda ^2 \mu ^2 x^4+\mu ^6 \left(\lambda ^2+24 x^2-12 \lambda  x\right)-3 \lambda  \mu ^4 x^2 (\lambda -4 x)\right)}{8 \mu ^6 x^6} \\
 4 & \frac{\lambda  e^{-\frac{\lambda  (x-\mu )^2}{2 \mu ^2 x}} \left(\lambda ^3 x^8-4 \lambda ^3 \mu ^2 x^6+6 \lambda ^2 \mu ^4 x^4 (\lambda -4 x)-4 \lambda  \mu ^6 x^2 \left(\lambda ^2+24 x^2-12 \lambda  x\right)+\mu ^8 \left(\lambda ^3-192 x^3+144 \lambda  x^2-24 \lambda ^2 x\right)\right)}{16 \mu ^8 x^8} \\
 5 & \frac{\lambda  e^{-\frac{\lambda  (x-\mu )^2}{2 \mu ^2 x}} \left(-\lambda ^4 x^{10}+5 \lambda ^4 \mu ^2 x^8-10 \lambda ^3 \mu ^4 x^6 (\lambda -4 x)+10 \lambda ^2 \mu ^6 x^4 \left(\lambda ^2+24 x^2-12 \lambda  x\right)-5 \lambda  \mu ^8 x^2 \left(\lambda ^3-192 x^3+144 \lambda  x^2-24 \lambda ^2 x\right)+\mu ^{10} \left(\lambda ^4+1920 x^4-1920 \lambda  x^3+480 \lambda ^2 x^2-40 \lambda ^3 x\right)\right)}{32 \mu ^{10} x^{10}} \\
\end{array}$$

Thank you @Steven Clark for providing this output. Do you think that we could derive a explicit (wrt $n$) of the derivative ?
